# How to convert a 2D shape into a 3D geometry by spinning in three.js?

Tags: three.js, mesh

What I want is simple but different from extrusion. For example, if I spin a 2D rectangle 360 degrees around its own axis (considering the origin is the COM), I create a cylinder. Similarly, if I spin a circle 180 degrees, I end up with a sphere.

Is there a way to do this in three.js? So far I've only seen Extrude Buffer Geometry which does not exactly do what I want.

Comment: Take a look at [`THREE.LatheGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/LatheGeometry) or [`THREE.LatheBufferGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/LatheBufferGeometry).

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Do you know how can I add thickness to the mesh I obtained with this way?

Comment: Change the figue that you rotate. For example, when you rotate a line, you'll get a hollow cylinder with thin side. When you rotate a narrow rectangle, you'll get a hollow cylinder, but it'll look like it's side has thickness.

Comment: I thought about that but the project requires for it to be actually filled. So I drew another line at an offset equal to thickness, then iterated over the points on both lines in small steps using .getPoint() and connected them.